# How do I apply currency or decimal formatting to all the numbers in a string without knowing their specific position in the string beforehand?

Tags: javascript, formatting

For example, if the text is: "the bouncy 7000 bunny hops 4 you".
I want: "the bouncy 70.00 bunny hops 4.00 you" returned.

I am aware that I could extract the text for numbers, marking the position of each number in the text, format the numbers and replace the marked positions in the text, but that seems tedious.

Is there a simpler way in javascript to do this?

Comment: Probably not. You'd have to use regex to search for all numbers and replace each one with the decimal formatting. There is no magical way of doing this.

Comment: At least give us rules of formatting: why 4 became 4.00 and why 7000 doesn't become 70000.00 ?

Comment: Because 4 is 4.00 monetarily and 7000 is not 70000.00. 4 has the same value as 4.00 but 7000 does not have the same value as 70000.00. I thought this was obvious. My apologies.

Comment: What's the diff between `7000` and `4` that makes first `70.00' and the second just `4.00` not `0.04`?

Comment: You got down voted because your question is not clear and you haven't actually tried anything. You should try writing some code before asking for help.

Comment: @Amir Its pretty audacious to assume I did not attempt to solve the problem before I posted. I was looking for a simpler solution is all. Also, I understand why the post may have been confusing now, thanks for clearing that up mortezaT and kevin, and thanks for posting a simple answer as was asked, mortezaT.

Comment: @TheHumblePedestrian for the future, you should provide the code you tried because otherwise we will assume you haven't tried anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the values over hundred should divided by 100 then this is the answer.

```js
var str = "the bouncy 7000 bunny hops 4 you";
console.clear();
var result = str
  .replace(/\d+/g, num => {
    num = parseInt(num);
    return (num > 100 ? num / 100 : num) + ".00";
  });
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @TheHumblePedestrian You'd better explain everything you want completely. Your downVotes are mostly because of this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) in conjunction with regular expressions to replace the relevant numbers with the desired ones.

Based on your specific example, you can get the desired result in the following way.

```js
    function getFormatted(arr) {
      return arr.map(function(str) {
        // if str ends in '00'
        if (str.substring(str.length - 2) === '00') {
          return str.substring(0, str.length - 2) + '.' + '00';
        // if str does NOT end in '00'
        } else if (str.substring(str.length - 2) !== '00') {
          return str + '.00';
        }
      })
    }

    function replacer(str, matches, formatted) {
      return matches.reduce(function(acc, cur, i) {
        return acc.replace(cur, formatted[i]);
      }, str)
    }
    
    var str = 'the bouncy 7000 bunny hops 4 you';
    
    var matches = str.match(/\d+/g);
    console.log(matches);
    // => ["7000", "4"]
    
    var formatted = getFormatted(matches);
    console.log(formatted);
    // => ["70.00", "4.00"]
    
    var replaced = replacer(str, matches, formatted);
    console.log(replaced);
    // => ["the bouncy 70.00 bunny hops 4.00 you"]
```

You may need to adjust the rules in `getFormatted` to tailor to your specific use cases.

**Update**

If you're looking for a simpler way of going about this, you can pass an array of arrays consisting of regular expressions and transform functions. This will take all of the matches of the regular expression (first argument) and apply a transform function to them (second argument).

```
var replacer = function(str, arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
    return acc.match(cur[0]).reduce(function(acc, cur) {
      return acc.replace(cur, cur[1](cur));
    }, str)
  }, str)
}

var replaced = replacer('the bouncy 7000 bunny hops 4 you', [
  [/\d+/g, function(match) { return match + '.00'; }],
  [/bunny/, function(match) { return 'dog'; })]
]);

console.log(replaced);
// = > "the bouncy 7000.00 dog hops 4.00 you"
```

Or if you are using ES6 syntax...

```
var replacer = (str, arr) => arr.reduce((acc, [reg, fn]) => {
    return acc.match(reg).reduce((acc, match) => {
      return acc.replace(match, fn(match));
    }, str);
  }, str);
}

var replaced = replacer('the bouncy 7000 bunny hops 4 you', [
  [/\d+/g, (match) => match + '.00'],
  [/bunny/, (match) => 'dog']
]);

console.log(replaced);
// = > "the bouncy 7000.00 dog hops 4.00 you"
```